# How to add methods to prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

So this is a part of my class

```
this.$e = function(el){
    element = document.querySelector( el );
    return {
        method1 : function(){
            element.className += " class1";
            return this;
        },
        method2 : function(){
            element.className += " class2";
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

And this one works perfectly to use it as such

```
$e(".myClass").method1().method2();
```

Now I wanna go a step further and add those methods to the `prototype` of the function.

I basically have no idea how.

I want it to look something like this

```
this.$e = function(el){
    element = document.querySelector( el );
    return element;
}

this.$e.prototype = {
    method1 : function(){
        this.element.className += " class1";
        return this;
    },
    method2 : function(){
        this.element.className += " class2";
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you construct these objects?

Comment: @RenatoZannon What do you mean by construct?

Comment: How do you create them? Do you have a constructor function?

Comment: @RenatoZannon Yes, they're inside of an object. It's just a `function myFunction(){ this.$e = ... }`. I want to use them inside this function, though.

Comment: Why do you add `$e` to `this`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest hoisting `$e` out of your constructor function:

```
function myFunction() {
  this.$e = function(el) {
    return new $E(el);
  };

  /* ... */
}

function $E(el) {
  this.element = document.querySelector( el );
}

$E.prototype.method1 = function() {
  this.element.className += " class1";
  return this;
};

$E.prototype.method2 = function() {
  this.element.className += " class2";
  return this;
};
```

Comment: No need to `return this` in an instance method

Comment: The `return this` is to fulfill the chaining requirement. Otherwise, `method1` and `method2` would return undefined.

Comment: Oh didn't notice the chaining. My bad